# Android ViewPager first and last pages fail on call onPause method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablelayout

I have a viewpager that instantiate the same fragment several times, this is because each page represents a form and i just change its ID and TYPE, so this is handle well, but, I am trying to save the data at the OnPauseMethod, but, when I swipe the first page to second page, this method is not called. The same happends with the last page when I swipe back from this.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: onPause is not called on swipe because you are not pausing activity as ViewPager just a child view of activity.

Comment: where did you listen the `onPause()`? Activity? Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

**OnPaus**e is not called when navigate through fragments on ViewPager, the method is tied to the Activity's **onPause** method (will be called only when the Activity's onResume() or onPause() is called). May be you should do that **onStop**